# Creating Marklogic docker instance in Ubuntu 16.04 exposing the ports

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have created a marklogic instance on Ubuntu 16.04 using a DockerFile. After the marklogic server is started, I try to access admin interface from the port 8000, 8001, 8002 etc, which are exposed in the creation of docker instance, but I encounter issue of server not started or page not found. Has anyone encountered this issue and how to circumvent it.

Comment: Can you show us your Dockerfile as well please just for the sake of completeness?

Comment: How do you expose the ports?

Comment: Dockerfile at the below link:
https://github.com/kgpavan/ml-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Try these three steps:

1. Confirm the Docker container is still running with

`docker ps`

If there is no container running, you probably need a command in the Dockerfile to keep the container running indefinitely. Try adding the following at the end of your Dockerfile:

`CMD tail -f /dev/null`

which will keep the container running indefinitely.

2. In your Dockerfile, confirm the EXPOSE setting contains the three ports you wish to access:

`EXPOSE 8000 8001 8002`

3. Confirm that the MarkLogic service is started in a command in the Dockerfile. For example in a default install of MarkLogic 8 on CentOS 7, I start the MarkLogic service in the Dockerfile with

`CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start`

Comment: All the steps mentioned are done. 
Dockerfile being used is at the link below:
https://github.com/kgpavan/ml-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @GaneshPavanKambhampati, are you still seeing getting the same error?